# how to differentiate between passwords saved as hashed and simple string

Tags: c#, linq, cryptography, password-hash

When i try login with correct username and password that is saved using [hashing algorithm](https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing) but there are some passwords saved as strings(not hashed). When i login using correct username and hashed password it works as expected but when i try to login using correct username and password(saved as string i.e not hashed) it gives an error stating *Input string was not in a correct format*  and if password is saved as integer doesn't matter wrong or right(non hashed) it gives *IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array*  exception. although from now on i am hashing every password but for some of which is already created, i want to use them as well.
i don't know how to do that. this is the code where i get the error

```
 var comparingPassword = PasswordHashManager.ValidatePassword(model.Password, correctPassword);
```

is there any way to check if password is hashed or not and if password is hashed then use comparingPassword otherwise use simple query to check login credentials.

Comment: You can't distinguish if a given string is a hash representation or not, Anything is(should be) valid as a password even if it already looks like a hash. If you save them as hashed or not mark them in the store you safe them to so you know if they are hashed or not and how you need to compare them. Said this your shown exception points more to a buggy implementation and should have nothing to do with a the given string. Debug your code.

Comment: the problem is that the ValidatePaasword method must be given hashed password which was specified in github documentation there fore when i give unhashed password it gives error i just somehow want to bypass them by using like if condition based on password length if hashed password is particualar length.

Answer (score 0):

Any decent password hash library has a function like `VerifyPassword(userEnteredPassword, hashStoredInDb)` and they require the user entered password together with the previously stored **hash** of the password. There is a huge security problem in your code, if the passwords are sometimes stored plaintext, and you should fix this instead of circumventing the problem.

Not sure what you mean with password saved as integer, but keep in mind that the function [GetHashCode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode?view=net-6.0#system-string-gethashcode) is in no way a password hash function, instead use the `CreateHash()` of the password hash library, they are not compatible.

P.S. There are algorithms which are better suited for password hashing, like Argon2, BCrypt or SCrypt, so think about switching to another library.

Comment: the password which is in plaintext was stored before using hashing-password library. i was just looking for way to login using those passwords as well, for hash creation of password, i have used CreateHash().

Comment: @SalmanAbbas - Was the library introduced at a certain date, then maybe you could search for all rows with an older creation date and hash them?

Comment: what i did was used if(password.length > 20) if true i'll use ValidatePassword() method because hashed password would be atleast 50 character long. otherwise use old implentation. but the logic you suggested seem much better.

Comment: @SalmanAbbas -You could also check for the exact length, because a hash function will always produce output of the same length.